# Is it possible to map just part of a file using mmap?

Tags: c, memory, pointers, memory-management, memory-mapped-files

I have a input file which has a header like this:

```
P6\n
width\n
height\n
depth\n
```

and then a struct is writen, pixel*, into this file, which is going to be mapped.

So, I want to skip the header and make my mmap function return the ptr to that structure. How can I do this? with lseek perhaps? Could you please exemplify?

I will leave part of my code here:

```
printf("Saving header to output file\n");
    if (writeImageHeader(h, fpout) == -1) {
        printf("Could not write to output file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    last_index = (int)ftell(fpout);
    //printf("offset after header= %d\n",last_index);

    //alloc mem space for one row (width * size of one pixel struct)
    row = malloc(h->width * sizeof (pixel));

    /*Create a copy of the original image to the output file, which will be inverted*/
    printf("Starting work\n");
    for (i = 0; i < h->height; i++) {
        printf("Reading row... ");
        if (getImageRow(h->width, row, fpin) == -1) {
            printf("Error while reading row\n");
        }
        printf("Got row %d || ", (i + 1));

        printf("Saving row... ");
        if (writeRow(h->width, row, fpout) == -1) {
            printf("Error while reading row\n");
        }
        printf("Done\n");
    }


    /*Open file descriptor of the ouput file.
     * O_RDWR -  Read and Write operations both permitted
     * O_CREAT - Create file if it doesn't already exist
     * O_TRUNC - Delete existing contents of file*/
    if ((fdout = open(argv[2], O_RDWR, FILE_MODE)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't create %s for writing\n", argv[2]);
        exit(1);
    }

    /*Get size of the output file*/
    if (fstat(fdout, &sbuf) == -1) {
        perror("Stat error ---------->\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    //printf("Size of output file: %d\n",(int)sbuf.st_size);

    /*Maps output file to memory*/
    if ((data = mmap((caddr_t) 0, sbuf.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fdout, 0)) == (caddr_t) (-1)) {
        perror("Error mmaping");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

As you see, right now my ppm image is mapped to `char*` data, but I want to skip the header and map just to the `pixel*` part.

Here's my code with the suggestion of using 2 pointers, a char* from mmap and another one equals that + offset.

[main](http://www.pastethat.com/mminverterv2)
[c functions](http://www.pastethat.com/ppmtools)
[header](http://www.pastethat.com/ppmheader)
[makefile](http://www.pastethat.com/mmfmakefile)

Comment: Why not just use a bit of pointer arithmetic and one more pointer variable?

Comment: Note that `caddr_t` is legacy nonsense from pre-ANSI C. The type used with `mmap` is `void *`.

Comment: @R..: So how can I call the mmap in a correct way?This was from a teacher example, lol

Comment: You can find the correct prototype and usage for `mmap` here: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html Might be useful if your teacher tries to "correct" you and insists on writing `caddr_t` nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the man page for `mmap`, you wil find that its final parameter is `off_t offset`.  The description:

> ...  continuing or at most 'len' bytes to be mapped from the object described by 'fd', starting at byte offset 'offset'.

I suspect if you pass your offset in as that parameter, it will do what you want.

Comment: Not unless offset is a multiple of 4096 (or whatever the machine's page size is).

Answer (score 1):

You can't if the amount you need to skip is less than the system page size, since `offset` must be a multiple of the page size on some systems.

Comment: At least on my system it says `If offset or len is not a multiple of the pagesize, the mapped region may extend past the specified range.`  That implies that it ought to work, but it's certainly worth checking.

Comment: @Steven: It says `offset must be a multiple of the page size as returned by sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE).` here.

Comment: Guess my mmap is more awesomer than yours :-p  I wish such incompatibilities were documented better.

Comment: @Steven: There's nothing "awesomer" about a `mmap` implementation that silently fails to share the actual cache pages. This will probably lead to all sorts of synchronization errors/race conditions and will at the very least waste lots of memory.

Comment: @R.: I was (I thought!) clearly being tongue in cheek there.  I would hope that if the performance is reduced it would be documented, but not all my hopes come true...

Answer (score 1):

You just need to keep 2 pointers - the pointer to the start of the `mmap`'d block, and the pointer to the start of the data you want inside there. As in:

```
unsigned char *block = mmap(0, sbuf.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fdout, 0);
unsigned char *data = block + offset;
```

where `offset` is the offset in the file to the data you want.

Comment: Could you please exemplify? I'm not understanding... too many hours on this.Sorry

Comment: and is that data the actual part that was mapped? I can use pixel* instead of char* right?

Comment: You really need to do your initial pointer arithmetic as `char` pointers since offsets will be in units of bytes, not a larger type. After you get the data pointer you can cast it to whatever else (as long as it's suitably aligned for accessing that type).

Comment: UHm, ok. I didn't know that. I've tried, my image ins inverted but it still has garbage on the left side..damn! I will leave my current code if some of you can see and try...please?

Answer (score 0):

So, from what I understand, can I do something like this?

```
off_t offset_after_header = lseek(fdout, last_index, SEEK_SET);
    printf("Pointer is on %d\n",(int)offset_after_header);
    /*Maps output file to memory*/
    if ((data = mmap((caddr_t) 0, sbuf.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fdout, offset_after_header)) == (caddr_t) (-1)) {
        perror("Error mmaping");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

and, from that, I could map my file to whatever type I want, in this case the `pixel*`

If this is ok, what cautions should I take? For example, like those Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams said

Answer (score -1):

Um, you did notice the 'offset' parameter that you are supplying with a zero? Assuming you know the absolute offset of what you want, you pass it.